# Example of a non closed linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have just read that an operator $T$ is closed if, $\forall x_0\in D$, considered every sequence $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ such that $T x_n$ is convergent, we have that every $Tx_n\rightarrow Tx_0$.

In a book, I found an example of a linear operator which is not closed:
$$
Te_n=e_1,
$$
where $n=1,2,\dots$ and $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis.

Considering another orthonormal basis, given by
$$
f_1=(e_1-e_2)/\sqrt{2}
$$
$$
f_2=(e_1+e_2-2e_3)/\sqrt{6}
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
f_n=(e_1+e_2+\dots +e_n-ne_{n+1})/\sqrt{n(n+1)}
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
one notices that $Tf_n=0$ for any $n=1,2,\dots$

How can I prove that $T$ is not a closed operator using the latter basis?

**Edit**: There is a footnote about the example:

> What is the Kernel of $T$? Is it a subspace dense in $H$? Is it possible to approximate, for instance, $e_1$ with a sequence of vectors belonging to $\text{Ker}(T)$? Notice that $T$ shows many 'pathologies': for instance one can prove that $e_1$ does not belong to the domain of the adjoint operator $T^+$.

Comment: I think that you have misread the example from your book.  The operator you have described is bounded (i.e. continuous) and therefore closed.

Comment: Is it? Because I checked the book and it is shown as an example of non closed (therefore non continuous) operator. I am adding to the question a footnote in the example's page.